# How can I read the serial number of an SSL certificate using C# or VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a project where I need to be able to compare an expected SSL certificate serial number with the actual serial number of the certificate I retrieve from the server. How can I do this in C# or VB?

Comment: Not my languages, and links are not answers.  But I would start here if I were working on it  http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2

Answer (score 0):

You should use [x509certificate2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Url of the site");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
var cerificateFromClient = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;   

X509Certificate2 certificateFromServer = new X509Certificate2("path to certificate", "Passwod");
var serialFromClient = cerificateFromClient.GetSerialNumberString();
var serialFromServer = certificateFromServer.GetSerialNumberString();  

//Checking if both the serial numbers are same
bool isSame = string.Equals(serialFromClient, serialFromClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [X509Certificate2.SerialNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.serialnumber(v=vs.110).aspx) Property.